# rostopic echo with launch file

Tags: matlab, roslaunch, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to do something like this

```
rostopic echo -p /mytopic > outputfile.txt
```

with the launch file

Hence, I wrote this in the launch file

```
<node name="output_topic1" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" output="screen" args="echo -p /mytopic > outputfile.txt">
</node>
```

However, it doesn't work and give me an error like this

```
Usage: rostopic echo [options] /topic

rostopic: error: you may only specify one input topic

[output_topic1-8] process has died [pid 11643, exit code 2, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rostopic/rostopic echo -p /mytopic > outputfile.txt __name:=output_topic1 __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/edae921e-f970-11e2-be82-14feb5b7467c/output_topic1-8.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/edae921e-f970-11e2-be82-14feb5b7467c/output_topic1-8*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70009/rostopic-echo-with-launch-file/) by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am very sorry, I haven't check this for a while. I am no longer using ROS. I believe this was working for me three years ago.

```
<launch>
  <arg name ="file_name" default="your_bag_file.bag"/>
  <arg name ="dest_path" default="path_to_the_destination"/>
  <arg name ="topic1" default="/topic_name_1"/>
  <arg name ="topic2" default="/topic_name_2"/>
  <arg name ="topic3" default="/topic_name_3"/>
  <arg name ="topic4" default="/topic_name_4"/>
  <node name ="recorder" pkg="rosbag" type="record" output="screen" args="-O $(arg dest_path)/$(arg file_name) $(arg topic1) $(arg topic2) $(arg topic3) $(arg topic4)">
  </node>
</launch>
```

@Druff @atp @Andrew.A

---

Originally posted by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) with karma: 215 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2016-03-28**:
So....I guess I didn't really manage to get .txt file directly out from the topic(s)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't  used rostopic echo in launch file, but i feel that "type" parameter should have value "echo" and then args should be topic name.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-07-30**:
if you start rostopic via rosrun, the command is "rosrun rostopic rostopic echo "
so the type is rostopic and the args should be echo, have you tried it without the "> outputfile.txt" ? Does it work then ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-31**:
I haven't tried it but I feel that ">output.txt" is a very generic command used to store the contents published on terminal into a file. Therefore roslaunch is not accepting it.

**Comment by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on 2013-07-31**:
@ayush_dewan that's mean there's no way I could do this in roslaunch?
@coon It works without the  "> outputfile.txt", I mean it runs without error but I'm not sure if it print anything out to the terminal

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-31**:
@coon@Maytheewat Sorry I am unable to test this right now, so I am not certain about my claim. Since the objective is to store contents of a topic in file, so instead of using rostopic echo write a simple subscriber file ans then store the contents in a file.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-05-26**:
@Maytheewat Hi, did you eventually manage to get this working? I'm also looking at a similar way to write contents from a published topic to a file.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-10-29**:
I'm interested in this as well.

**Comment by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on 2016-03-28**:
I am also very much interested